# How to (locally) unit test storing images with Firebase Cloud Storage

Tags: android, firebase, unit-testing, firebase-storage, firebase-tools

I'm using Firebase Emulator Suite to unit test my database content. Now I want to add a "make a picture" feature to my app. In the productive version the images should be stored in Firebase Cloud Storage.

Is there a way to emulate uploading and downloading data to mocking the Firebase Cloud Storage access in order to integrate this into my unit tests?

The Firebase Emulator Suite itself doesn't provide this feature.

I guess it's not a good idea to use the real productive Firebase Cloud Storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

An emulator for Cloud Storage is part of the Firebase Emulator Suite now. See the documentation on using it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_storage)

Comment: Thank you Frank. 

I'm already watching the mentioned feature request.Since there hasn't been any new information there for a long time, I assume that it will take a while. So I'm looking for a useful workaround. Seems like there isn't one.

For unit tests, I will try to prevent access to cloud storage in emulation mode, but for release tests I will probably have to use cloud storage

Comment: the Firebase Cloud Storage emulator is live now ;-)

Comment: Good point.  I updated my answer to reflect that.